# Checking if value is null before assigning

Tags: c#

so I am creating a new object and setting its properties from other functions. I need to check if those are null before applying the values. How would I approach this?

```
Customer = new Customer (
     name = requestCall.Name, 
     age = requestCall.Age.ofType<DateTime>().DOB
    )
```

how would I check if requestCall.Age or requestCall.Name is not null before applying?

Comment: What do you want to happen if they are null? This code won't compile anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your scenario you can use [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
name = requestCall.Name == null ? something : something_else
```

or [null coalesce operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
name = requestCall.Name ?? something
```

Answer (score 2):

Variant 1:

```
Customer = new Customer(
     name = requestCall.Name ?? "default name", 
     age = requestCall.Age == null ? (some default date) :  requestCall.Age.ofType<DateTime>().DOB
);
```

Variant 2:

```
Customer = requestCall == null ? null : new Customer(
     name = requestCall.Name, 
     age = requestCall.Age.ofType<DateTime>().DOB
);
```

Of course, you can use `if` and to my mind, it is better:

```
Customer customer;
if (requestCall != null)
{
    customer = new Customer();
    if (requestCall.Name != null)
    {
        customer.Name = requestCall.Name;
    }
    // etc.
}
else
{
    customer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a `requestCall.IsValid()` method (aptly named something that fits in with your usage) and use this to verify whether or not you are able to make a new customer.

I'd imagine the logic will grow as you determine other things that need to be added and this will reduce the amount of updating you'll have to do.

As a side note to this: You may wish to make a constructor that takes in a `requestCall` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Customer = new Customer (
     name = requestCall.Name ?? string.Empty, 
     age = requestCall.Age.ofType<DateTime>().DOB ?? DateTime.Now
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as

```
 requestCall.Name ?? "soome text",
```

or `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestCall.Name) ? requestCall.Name : "soome text"` ,

and check null for integer as

```
 `age = requestCall.Age == null ? (default) :  requestCall.Age.ofType<DateTime>().DOB`
```