# IList property automatic get set

Tags: c#

Currently, If I want to declare a property for my class, I write this line of code:

```
public string Target { get; set; }
```

Now for IList (generics), I do something like this:

```
IList<Result> _Results;
public IList<Result> Results
{
    get
    {
        if (_Results == null)
            _Results = new List<Result>();
        return _Results;
    }
    set
    {
        _Results = value;
    }
}
```

in `get` section I check if the list is null, then I will create a new one...
How can I avoid this part and have a less and more clear code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595461/checking-if-value-is-null-before-assigning ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if value is null before assigning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595461/checking-if-value-is-null-before-assigning)

Comment: the duplicates seems to be the answer, but they are not about properties and the initialization of private fields. IMHO not an exact duplicate

Comment: When there is possibility, that the setter can set to null and the getter need to fix this, there is probably no other way around this code.

Comment: "more clear code?"  for me this is as clear as it get's. Entirely obvious at the first glance, and very readable.

Comment: **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)**

Comment: As @Disaffected1070452 pointed out `public IEnumerable<Result> Results {get}` would be much cleaner and less confusing. Otherwise one would never know if your class owns the list or just refers to some randomly changing one for example...

Answer (score 3):

If using C# 6 you can use [null-coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator `??`:

```
IList<Result> _Results;
public IList<Result> Results
{
    get => _Results ?? (_Results = new List<Result>());

    set
    {
        _Results = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6 or higher, you can do:

```
public IList<Result> Results { get; set; } = new List<Result>();
```

Comment: this is not equal, the initialization happens at constructor call not at the time of property getter access like in the post

Comment: And another problem is, the setter can always set the property to null.